# What does Configuration.AddAssembly("") in NHibernate do?

Tags: nhibernate

What does the below code actually do in NHibernate:

```
<mapping assembly="Sample" /> //in the config file
```

OR

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.AddAssembly("Sample");   //in the code file
```

Also does this "Sample" correspond to the the main namespace of the Project in .NET or can it be the name of any Business Object in our application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can have .hbm.xml files spread out to many assemblies. So either way, instructs NHibernate from where to load those files.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have 3 .hbm.xml files: Cust, Order and Prod (and their corresponding Business Entities) in a WebApplication named as Project1; then I have the option of adding all the three files at once if I use AddAssembly("Project1") and I also have the option of loading each file separately by using AddAssembly("Cust") and so on ?

Comment: no, the AddAssembly() works only with the assembly (by default project) name. So AddAssembly("Cust") is invalid. There is however a method (which i don't remember from memory) that allow to load .hbm.xml files selectively

Answer (score 4):

It adds all the embedded resources with names ending in `.hbm.xml` from the specified assembly as mappings.

Namespaces have nothing to do with this.